# How to eliminate repetitive SQL queries to execute in different table names

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, foreach

I have a code block is being executed repeatedly but only the table name is being changed.

```
 SQLData stagingData = runtime.SQLExecuteQuery(integrationDatabase, "SELECT COUNT (*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM *<DATABASE NAME>*");

        foreach(SQLDataRow stagingDataRow in stagingData)
        {
            stageCount = runtime.SQLDataRowGetInteger(stagingDataRow, "ROW_COUNT");
        }

        if(stageCount !=0)
        {
            writeStaging = runtime.SQLExecuteStoredProcedure(integrationDatabase, "*<STORED PROCEDURE NAME>*", 0);
            SQLData transformedData = runtime.SQLExecuteQuery(integrationDatabase,
                "SELECT COUNT (*) AS ERROR_COUNT FROM *<TABLE NAME>* WHERE " +
                "[Entity] LIKE '_ERROR_%' OR [Name] LIKKE '_ERROR_'%");

            foreach (SQLDataRow transDataRow in transformedData)
            {
                errorCount = runtime.SQLDataRowGetInteger(transDataRow, "ERROR_COUNT");
            }

            if (errorCount == 0)
            {
                writeTransformed = runtime.SQLExecuteStoredProcedure(integrationDatabase, "*<STORED PROCEDURE NAME>*", 0);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This is the code block that is being executed repeatedly. The items that are *Italicized* are the only thing that varies.

We would want to reduce the number of lines for this part but we just couldn't find a good structuring to do it.

We hope to hear about your suggestions.

*P.S.* We execute this inside a class.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't parameterize object names in SQL. So... the best you're going to get is some kind of templated portion, getting the table name / sproc name from somewhere (which could be configuration, attributes like `[SomeTableName("Foo")]`, method parameters, virtual properties on an abstract base type, etc). There's no real tidy/magic solution here, sorry.

Comment: this sounds like you should have made 1 table with the error type in, not 1 table per..

Comment: SQLServer has some commands that execute string queries. I don't know if MySql has such a thing. If it has you can create a stored procedure in your database maybe. You C# code will look better after that!

Comment: @AliDoustkani that just moves the ugliness. You're talking about things like `sp_executesql`, but: that *still* can't parameterize schema/object/column names - so all you'd end up doing is moving the string concat/replace from C# to SQL. I don't see that as an advantange, and in many ways it is a disadvantage. SQL *can do* string operations, but C# is *much much better at them* (in terms of convenience and readability).

Comment: Thank you for the comments/suggestions, I'll keep these in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually bad schema design to need to do the same thing to multiple tables.  Please elaborate on your schema.

You can write a Stored Procedure to construct (via `CONCAT`, `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`) the same query on multiple tables.  It could also interrogate `information_schema.TABLES` to discover the table names.

`SELECT COUNT (*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM *<DATABASE NAME>*` is not possible.  You can do `COUNT(*)` on a *table*, but not a *database*.  (Terminology issue?  A "database" contains several "tables"; a table contains "rows" of data.)